# How to get size of image from Uri

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I get image Uri by

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()){uri = it}

launcher.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))
```

and I need to get size of this image
I tried to use

```
val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(uri)
return painter.intrinsicSize
```

but this returns Unspecified size

and

```
val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.path, options)
Log.d("MyLog", "${options.outWidth}, ${options.outHeight}")
return IntSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight)
```

but it returns IntSize(0, 0)

How can I get width and height of image?

Comment: uri.path is nonsense. Use the whole uri. Open an inputstream for the uri an use BitmapFactory to decode the stream.

Comment: `I get image Uri by` That tells us nothing as you are not telling what you launch. Nor shiw where you get the uri.

Answer (score 0):

its happened with

```
fun Uri.imageSize(context: Context): IntSize{
    val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true

    context.contentResolver.openInputStream(this).use {
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it, null, options)
        return IntSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight)
    }
}
```

Comment: As above solution returns IntSize, one can use above solution for Jetpack Compose or can change return type to Map for general use.